# How to select an id inside a different page

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to make a control panel where I can modify paragraphs in my main.html webpage with javascript. The control panel will be an individual page and I was wondering, how can I select the id from within my main.html page if the code itself is on the separate admin.html page? Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also you will need to save it somewhere, so you will also have to trigger the admin save...

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?67448-document-getElementById-from-another-page

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript code you need to have syntax similar to the following:

```
function your_fun_name()
{
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("id_u_want_selected");

// other part of the code

}
```

It's advisable you keep your javascript file seperate and put some event to call the function passing argument as the id of that paragraph.